# Magento Fishpig Wordpress module, Associated Blog Posts to products

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

In Magento admin section, When I am trying relate the products with the wordpress posts, the frontend page is shown instead of the gridview with the wordpress posts, I'm using the full integration and database separated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. It was caused by having Wordpress and Magento in two separated databases. I fixed it by re-installing Wordpress in the same database as Magento and then re-installing the extension. (Be aware that you have to change the extension settings after that.)

Comment: Thanks, The developers publish a new version that fix the issue,.! Cheers